# VS 2015 "Add Connected Service" -> "Mobile Services" - Configure button disabled

Tags: azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I just created a new Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2015 RC.  I want to use my Azure Mobile Service I created via the portal, so I right clicked on the References for the Portable app project in the solution and selected the "Add Connected Service..." menu item.  It brings up the dialog to let me select what kind of Azure service I want to connect.  By default it shows:

Application Insights, Azure Mobile Services, and Azure Storage.

There is a configure button at the bottom that is disabled for all choices except the Azure Storage.

How do I add my Azure Mobile Service to my Xamarin Forms project so I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a [blog post](http://blog.falafel.com/cross-platform-apps-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-mobile-services/) where someone describes how he does it. Maybe it is of any help to you?

In addition I noticed there is a Xamarin component by Microsoft which adds functionality for Azure Mobile services, you can find it [here](http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services).

Comment: Found this sample code from GitHub that was very helpful, too.  It uses the same WindowsAzure.MobileServices Nuget package that the blog post example uses.  https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/TodoListXamarinForms

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin projects are currently not supported by the Azure Mobile Service Connected Service tool in VS.  On the right side of the dialog there is a link to [Request Support](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/265038-connected-services).  Adding an idea to User Voice is the easiest way to get the product team to add the features you want.

So for now, you will need to add it manually as suggested in @GeraldVersluis's answer.